# Getting a 400 when saving metadata

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've created a .NET web application, which upload files to the Azure Storage as blobs.

This works fine however, it goes wrong when I add a specific metadata tag.
If I add a "Description" metadata tag with a quite large value (tested with ~425 characters long) I receive a 400 Bad Request error.
 When I do this manually with the Azure Management Portal there are no problems.

Code used:

```
blob.Metadata["Description"] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam non nisi suscipit, dignissim nibh quis, imperdiet metus. Donec elementum nunc nec mi mollis, eget rhoncus lorem aliquam. Sed gravida, elit at elementum euismod, ligula arcu viverra mauris, consectetur commodo sem dui id tortor. Duis rutrum libero at ante tincidunt posuere. Aliquam turpis arcu, pellentesque ac purus vitae, eleifend consectetur lectus imperdiet ornare.";
blob.SetMetadata();
```

Edit: It now gives 400 error instead of 403. (Bad Request instead of Forbidden)

Edit 2: After some more testing I figured out it puts '\n' characters in the String. Somehow this is causing my problems. (It is still allowed to do in the Azure Management Portal)

Comment: I just tried it using the values you used above on a blob in my storage account and it worked fine. Can you please check if you're able to perform other operation on blob like reading properties (`FetchAttributes`)?

Comment: I've updated my question. Somehow it adds '\n'

Comment: What do you mean by `it adds '\n'`? Can you please clarify.

Comment: Well not visible in text editors, but there are '\n' in the text.
For some reason, those are not allowed (?)

Comment: Also I figured that if you add '\n' in the Azure Management Portal it escapes the backslash. So you you cannot have a '\n' in your metadata.

Comment: This is what is mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx (Go to section titled "Constructing the Canonicalized Headers String") - `Unfold the string by replacing any breaking white space with a single space.`

Comment: I solved my problem by encoding the string. Just in case the escape character is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final problem was it could not accept escape charaters.
I fixed this issue by encoding and decoding the string.

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some value with a \n in it."));
```

And to get it back

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("U29tZSB2YWx1ZSB3aXRoIGEgCiBpbiBpdC4="));
```

This solves the problem. So thanks for the support. (Gaurav Mantri)

Answer (score 0):

FYI for others, this is a bug to be addressed in a future release: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/30093

> In Azure Storage Explorer, I can assign a newline character ('\n') to
>   a blob Metadata value without any issues. However, when I call
>   cloudBlockBlob.SetMetadata() or cloudBlockBlob.SetMetadataAsync() with
>   a value containing the newline character, it fails.
>
> Someone else reproduced the same issue in this SO thread, but the
>   documentation referenced in one of the comments does not exist
>   anymore.
>
> The current documentation indicates that any ASCII characters should
>   work for Metadata values, and a backslash and 'n' would both be
>   considered valid ASCII characters.

Comment: Was this ever fixed?